# UITextView not word wrapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm new to IOS development, and I'm just trying to get my head around all the views. At first I have a UITextField which is one line and I wanted it to wrap. I was told to implement a UITextView instead - and that worked! I then had many lines of wrapped text.

The next thing I wanted to do was have horizontally scrolling pages. I downloaded apple's [page control example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html). In it many pages are created with a little text label. I altered this to contain a very long string, and replaced the UILabel type with a UITextView. However, it's not word wrapping! The cause could be anything an I have absolutely no idea what it might be. Perhaps it's inheriting some setting from something?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit - here is where the views are created:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page
{
if (page < 0)
    return;
if (page >= kNumberOfPages)
    return;

MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
{
    controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    [controller release];
}

if (controller.view.superview == nil)
{
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

    NSDictionary *numberItem = [self.contentList objectAtIndex:page];

    controller.numberTitle.text = [numberItem valueForKey:NameKey];
}
}
```

and this is the MyViewController header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
UILabel *pageNumberLabel;
int pageNumber;

UITextView *numberTitle;
UIImageView *numberImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *pageNumberLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *numberTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *numberImage;

- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page;

@end
```

Comment: Please post some code of your UITextView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the frame of the UITextView.  It's possible if you just swapped UITextView with UILabel that the frame is not large enough.  Change the frame to have a larger height.  Also, set the background color to a bright color so you know can see how large it is on the screen.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that unfortunately.

Comment: Did you increase "numberTitle" size in Interface Builder?  Before it was a UILabel and was probably not very large.

Comment: I've never used interface builder. How and where would I do this programatically?

Comment: hang on, in the xib there is actually a small UILabel which is where the text is being drawn to, but why does it work when I changed the code to a textview?

Comment: If IB still has the numberTitle as a UILabel you should delete it and add a UITextView.  Be sure to hook up the new UITextView to your IBOutlet.

Comment: To add programmatically, numberTitle = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)] autorelease]; [controller.view addSubview:numberTitle]; numberTitle.text = @"Hello";

Answer (score 0):

Even though everything in the program was changed, the xib file still contained a UILabel which is what was displaying the text.